# Problem in an ellipse circumscribed on an auxiliary circle

Tags: coordinate-systems, orbital-motion, geometry, celestial-mechanics, binary-stars

I was reading the book "an introduction to the evolution of single and binary stars", by Mattew Benacquista, and I couldn't understand a specific step in topic 2.1 (Time-Depedent Orbits), which says the following:

[image]

Consider an ellipse with semimajor axis a that is circumscribed by a circle of radius a, as shown in Fig. Referring to the figure, the following line segments and angles can be defined:

$$ a = \text{semimajor axis} $$

$$O \Pi = a$$

$$S \Pi = a(1-e)$$

$$ OS = ae $$

We want to find the time dependence of the eccentric anomaly, E.

The auxiliary circle has the property that:

$$\frac{PR}{QR} = \frac{b}{a} = \sqrt{1-e^{2}}$$

How did the book arrive at this conclusion since it would be logical to consider these conditions if points P and Q were parallel to the center?

Answer (score 0):

This comes from the definition of the ellipse as squished circle along the *y*-axis.

If the parametric equation of the circle is

$$ \pmatrix{x \\ y} = \pmatrix{ a \cos t \\ a \sin t} $$

which solves the implicit circle function

$$ \left( \frac{x}{a} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{y}{a} \right)^2 = 1$$

then for an ellispe of semi-minor axis $b = a \sqrt{1-e^2}$ the parametric equation and implicit function is

$$ \pmatrix{x \\ y} = \pmatrix{ a \cos t \\ b \sin t} $$

$$ \left( \frac{x}{a} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{y}{b} \right)^2 = 1$$

As you can see, the two equations vary in the *y*-axis by a factor of $b/a$ in both forms.

Hence $y_{\rm ellipse} = \tfrac{b}{a}\; y_{\rm circle}$ or specifically $PR = \tfrac{b}{a} QR$.

In addition, when viewed from on of the foci (like point S), the polar form of the ellipse is $$ r(\theta) =a \frac{1-e^2}{1+e \cos \theta} = \frac{b^2}{a \left(1+e \cos \theta\right) } $$